# Tag Soup, or, how to learn to stop worrying and love a lot of tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Consider, please, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054962/fastest-algorithm-to-calculate-the-normalized-and-engineering-scientific-notatio). The tags are so general and meta as to, in my view, add no information at all. But, as my finger hovered over the edit button, I found myself unable of thinking of one or more good alternatives. Suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

**[Scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scientific-notation/)** would be a good alternative, replacing both number and numerical. They are very meta! The question could possibly be tagged with "floating point" or "notation" too.

But I think that three good tags are probably sufficient: Algorithm, performance and scientific notation.

Comment: Good call.  I made the change.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Very fast!